# How to show the currency sign after the value in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, persian

I'm using Persian culture in my `asp.net` application.

I show prices as

```
PriceLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:C0}", 12000);
```

Which results in `12,000 ريال` where `ريال` is the Persian currency sign, but I want the currency sign to come after the value (Persian is left to right, so, by "after", I mean to the left side of the number).

I have tried `Style="text-align: right"` on `PriceLabel`, and `dir="rtl"` on the `<td>` tag containing the label, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-Ir");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 3;

var result = string.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C0}", 12000);

Console.WriteLine(result);
//Result
//12,000 ريال
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET libraries are doing what they should be, and showing the currency in the format you requested. To change this, you would be breaking i18n, but you might try using String.Format if you know the Unicode value for the Persian currency sign, e.g.

```
PriceLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", 12000, <insert unicode char here>);
```

I will freely admit that this is a guess, and definitely not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The following snipped will convert to the Persian money format when you are typing in the text box:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal Number;
    if (decimal.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out Number))
    {
        textBox3.Text = string.Format("{0:N0}", Number);
        textBox3.SelectionStart = textBox3.Text.Length;
    }
}
```